# How to scrape a page that doesn't load unless you click the pagination button

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website with Python BeautifulSoup. The website is paginated. The scaping works until page 201. For page 201, the URL returns a 404 if you copy it, and paste it in your browser, and hit enter. However, if you click the pagination button, it loads.

How do I handle this kind of scenario?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import logging
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}


def fetch_pagination_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        next_page = soup.select_one('.pagination__link--next')
        
        if next_page:
            next_url = next_page.get('href')        
            url = urljoin("https://mywebsite.com/",next_url) # type: ignore
            logging.info(f"next url: {url}")
            return url


def fetch_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.text
    ## Return error and terminate the program if the response status code is not 200
    logging.error(f"error fetching data from {url}")
    return None


def parse_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    courses = soup.find_all('div', class_='grid__item')
    data = []

    for course in courses:
        course_data = {}

        title_element = course.find('h2', class_=['h4', 'course-title'])
        if title_element:
            course_data['title'] = title_element.text.strip()
        else:
            course_data['title'] = None

        provider_element = course.find('div', class_='provider')
        if provider_element:
            course_data['provider'] = provider_element.text.strip()
        else:
            course_data['provider'] = None

        location_element = course.find('div', class_='location')
        if location_element:
            course_data['location'] = location_element.text.strip()
        else:
            course_data['location'] = None

        data.append(course_data)

    return data


def save_data(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        # Add more fieldnames as needed
        fieldnames = ['title', 'provider', 'location']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)


def main():
    page = 1
    output_filename = 'output.csv'

    # Write the header row to the CSV file
    with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['title', 'provider', 'location']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

    while True:
        url = f"https://website.com/coursedisplay/results/courses?studyYear=2023&destination=Undergraduate&postcodeDistanceSystem=imperial&pageNumber=200&sort=MostRelevant&clearingPreference=None"
        html = fetch_data(url)
        if html:
            data = parse_data(html)
            save_data(data, output_filename)
            logging.info(f"scraping page {page}")
            page += 1
        else:
            break

        # Add a delay to avoid overwhelming the server
        time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(3000000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It probably depends on whether the information for the page in question is provided correctly or to what extent it deviates from it. what is the corresponding url so that you don't have to guess?

Comment: The URL is consistent, just that it returns a 404 if you paste it on the address bar and hit enter. But if you click on the pagination link, and compare the resulting URL it is the same.

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: https://digital.ucas.com/coursedisplay/results/courses?studyYear=2023&destination=Undergraduate&postcodeDistanceSystem=imperial&pageNumber=201&sort=MostRelevant&clearingPreference=None

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to use a session to store the cookies and headers of the requests, so that the server recognizes that you are making consecutive requests

`s = requests.Session()`